# How to mount a bigger file to docker compose

Tags: python, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

The issue is as long as the file size is small: I could mount the volume and see it inside my container. But as the file size grows let's say 34MB, I can't see it.

is there any way I can mount this larger file to my container?
My docker-compose:

```
datascience-notebook:
    image: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}:/home/jovyan/work"
      - "${PWD}/lib/libdrillodbc_sb64.so:/home/jovyan/work/ibdrillodbc_sb64.so"
    ports:
      - 10000:8888
    container_name: jupyter_notebook
```

I would like to mount `libdrillodbc_sb64.so` from the local to the remote container, But I couldn't see it. Is there any way I could map it?
EDIT:
I could `libdrillodbc_sb64.so` in the mounting area of the container.
[image: InsideContainer] However when I log in to the jupyter lab ... i don't see them in GUI. [image: JupyterLab]as I run this in my jupyter lab I'm getting this error [image: File not found] when I can see the file exists with executable mode.

Comment: That mount looks suspicous: the left-hand side is a file, but the right-hand side is a directory. Shouldn't that be `- "${PWD}/lib/libdrillodbc_sb64.so:/home/jovyan/work/lib/libdrillodbc_sb64.so"`? There shouldn't be any file size limits on bind mounts.

Comment: you are right ... it was a typo, but still don't see this *.so file in my container. I think my volume is corrupted ... let me clean up and start again. I also thought there is no size limit.

Comment: I updated the question .... it's showing up inside the container but the only thing is I can't see them in the mounting area inside the container.

Comment: According to the error message, it's looking for `/work/ibdrillodbc_sb64.so`, but you've mounted it in `/home/jovyan/work/lib/ibdrillodbc_sb64.so`.

Comment: jupyter is hosted at home `/home/jovyan/`  so it's fine. just to be sure that it might be case, I tried with complete path, still have same error.